# How to change Rails app environment on Digital Ocean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, ruby-on-rails-5, ubuntu-16.04, digital-ocean

I have installed Rails application in Ubuntu+Nginx+Passenger server on Digital Ocean. The application has been installed for development environment and now I want to change the application environment to production.

I already researched on web and tried different approaches but I couldn't achieve the goal yet.

When I run `rails r "puts Rails.env"` it always showing me *development* as the result!

Adding few links below which I have tried-

[Link1](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/deploy) [Link2](https://ryanbigg.com/2015/07/deploying-a-rails-application-on-ubuntu-passenger-edition)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify:

```
"environment": "production",
```

in your `Passengerfile.json` config file for Phusion Passenger.  Read more about it on the Passenger docs here: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/deploy/standalone/deploy/ruby/#step-1-create-a-passenger-config-file.

Comment: Thanks! I already tried that but going to have another try and see if that works.

Comment: Tried again and the command `rails r "puts Rails.env" ` showing **development**!

Comment: When you run `rails r` you are running a new instance of rails and it defaults to development.  Try logging `Rails.env` from your rails web app itself and see if it is using production mode.